# How Can I Fix the error: expected identifier '(' in C

Tags: c, cs50

I don't understand what I am doing incorrectly I have searched several online references and still can't figure out what i am doing wrong. Here's my Code

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int x = 5;

int y=get_int("ENTER DIGIT HERE\n");

if (x>y) {
    printf("HI\n");

}else{
    printf("BYE\n");
}
```

Comment: You are missing a `main` function. I suggest you look carefully at some simple and short C programs to see the basic structure.

Comment: Most of the code presented can appear only inside a function.  Presumably `main()`, in this case.

Comment: I would suggest getting started with a [basic tutorial](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson1.html) so that the fundamentals don't trip you up. *Every full C program begins inside a function called "main"...*

Comment: As the DNT said, must have a function called main to executed call another part of your code and execute you program. Also, you need to ensure that you have the cs50.h library available in your system to use your code straightforward like we ca see here. If you don't understand so much, I will recommend explore a lot native libraries of C, like stdio.h, use scanf to get inputs, printf with format specifiers to understand the base of language. After you can check cs50.h and understand the usage better.

Comment: Admittedly, the error message doesn't help. I'm wondering how hard it would be for the compiler to show a better one, something like "Error: code should be inside a function". Probably harder than it looks for the general case, but for some special keywords (if, for, while...) it shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you want this:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)   // <<<< your code must be in the main function
{
   int x = 5;

   int y=get_int("ENTER DIGIT HERE\n");

   if (x>y) {
     printf("HI\n");
   } else {
     printf("BYE\n")
   }
}
```